# Getting multiple depth values of a pixel after projecting a mesh

Tags: opengl

I need to record multiple depth values at a pixel. I have a mesh and when projected on to the image, we could infer depth at a pixel location. This depth gives the nearest polygon distance.

But could we get depth values of all polygons that are being projected at pixel (x,y)?

If so, could someone provide help on how to do this in Opengl?

Comment: If you need to access depth info of all polygons in the fragment shader, an idea would be to project polygons to textures (with respect to camera), then pass them to the shader. But it might be quite infeasible if the number of polygons gets to high.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a naive way to do this.

But here's an idea.

First preallocate a few depth buffers, for example 16. That will be the maximum number of different depths you can store.

Clean all of the depth buffers to infinity (maximum depth).

Draw to the first depth buffer normally (`GL_LESS`).

For the following buffers we will draw differently though.
We will take the previous depth buffer as input to our fragment shader. In the fragment shader we do some sort of manual depth test.

```c
if(currentDepth <= previousDepth) {
    discard;
}
```

What we are doing here is "consider the fragment, only if it's further than the previous". The hardware depth test is doing it's thing at the same time.

So the result of each iteration is the closest fragment that is further than the previous. And we end up with "an array of depth slices".